# Nested structure array in Python

Tags: python, c++

I have a structure defined like so in C++ :

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)){
    uint16_t nb_elements; //2 bytes
    struct __attribute__((packed)){ // 6 bytes
        uint8_t identifier1; // 1 byte
        uint8_t identifier2; // 1 byte
        float my_data; // 4 bytes
    } element[];
} sElements;
```

(notice that `element` structures are nested in `sElements` structure).

I want to do the same thing in Python (using ctypes), and I am struggling at this point :

```
from ctypes import *    

class element(Structure):
  _fields_ = [("identifier1", c_uint, 8),
          ("identifier2", c_uint, 8),
          ("my_data", c_float, 64)]

class sElements(Structure):
  _fields_ = [("nb_elements", c_uint, 16)
          #I don't know what to put here !
         ]
```

**How could I reproduce this nested structure array in Python ?**

Comment: What do you want to do with that structure? If it's just for using it in a Python program, a simple `class` would be way easier...

Comment: I usually don't do bit fields for fun haha ! The goal is to send this structure via Serial, and receive it with a C program on the other side.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392203/dynamic-arrays-and-structures-in-structures-in-python

Comment: By doing so I am afraid that only a pointer is stored in the structure, thus, I can't transfer it through Serial. Am I right ? Or all the nested structures would be copied in the structure ?

Comment: It looks like you assigned my_data different sizes in the two. Also, you assume they both use the same underlying float encoding. (which they might actually do, but you should look into that)

Comment: I think you are mis-understanding the use of ctypes.  ctypes is used to share data with C code, not to serialize data to a specific format.  If you are going to send this data via `Serial` what you need to know is how the bytes will be arranged on the wire, not how they will appear in memory.  They are not the necessarily the same.

Comment: @StephenRauch You are right, I wanted to store the data in the memory the same as I wanted to send on the serial to just have to send sequential in-memory octets. But that is probably not the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did, it does not totally answer the question, but it solved my problem : (using bitstring)

```
import bitstring

class element():
    def __init__(self):
        self.identifier1 = None #uint:8
        self.identifier2 = None #uint:8
        self.my_data = None #float:64

    def serialize(self):
        return bitstring.pack('uint:8, uint:8, float:64', self.identifier1, self.identifier2, self.my_data)


class sElements():
    def __init__(self):
        self.nb_elements = None #uint:16
        self.element = [] #element list

    def serialize(self):
        serialized = bitstring.pack('uint:16', self.nb_elements)
        for elt in self.element:
            serialized += elt.serialize()
        return serialized
```

Modulo a possible endianness problem it allows to store those data (and send them) the way I want it.